# RESTful API for nested resource

Tags: rest, web-applications, restful-url

I have two entities `Hotel`, `Merchant` where each merchant can have many hotels. Right now I am having an API endpoint like this:

`/api/v1/merchants/{id}/hotels/{id}`

But I was thinking what is wrong with this semantics:

`/api/v1/hotels/{id}`

The later one is short too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience, the latter is preferable because it gives you more flexibility later. In six months somebody's going to say "Hey, I want to be able to look up all the hotels in Agraba". The first URL scheme makes that painful - you need to add a new endpoint. The second URL scheme supports that with a query parameter: `GET /hotels?location=Agraba`.

You may want to keep `/merchants/{id}/hotels` as a collection endpoint so you can POST/DELETE to add/remove hotels from a particular merchant.

Comment: I agree because ideally we should generate unique I'd for each instance of the entity. I was just confused about the REST semantics.

Comment: REST has nothing to say on URL design. In REST, URLs are opaque - they contain no semantic value. Semantic content in URLs is just an API design convenience for developers.

Comment: Nope. I'm saying that `GET /329ffkdq-dkfh/1234jfkdlf` is no different in REST than `GET /hotels/12`. @alexandrumarculescu is saying that you shouldn't support the same operations on `/hotels/12` and `/merchants/5/hotels/12` - the hotel should live in only one place.

Comment: That makes sense but now suppose I have many rooms inside hotels, then to find a room with AC `/rooms?facility=ac` would return all the rooms in every hotel but with url like `/hotels/id/rooms?facility=ac` I am sure that search would be confined within that hotel. What would you suggets?

Comment: @CodeYogi `GET /rooms?hotel=XXX&facility=YYY`

Comment: I see that hotel id is still there the only difference is that it's in the query string instead of path.

Answer (score 0):

In `REST`, each `URL` should uniquely identify a single resource.

So if the hotel's `id` is globally unique, then sure, there's no problem in using the shorter link. If however hotel id 1 means something different for merchant 1 than for merchant 2, then you ought to stick with the first `URL` (basically a unique composite key).

Comment: I have a single table for `hotel` so its id is likely to be unique.